# Find name of fonts used within Gimp xcf file

Tags: fonts, gimp

Is there a way to find name of fonts used within Gimp .xcf file?

Comment: Found out how... open it with something like scite or notepad++... Will answer my question in seven hours...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a linux console

```
grep -aPo 'font "(.*?)"' file.xcf
```

Sample output:

```
$ grep -aPo 'font "(.*?)"' file.xcf 
font "HP Simplified Italic"
font "Freehand521 BT"
font "Freehand521 BT"
```

Also you can look at the xcf with nano:

```
nano file.xcf
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on OS X.  I'm sure there is some different syntax for grep that I'm missing.

Comment: In this case the simplest thing to do is to open the xcf with a text editor and look for font " lines

Comment: For some reason it lists some fonts, but not the ones that are being used in my file.  I'm not sure why

Comment: If you have transferred the .xcf file to a system that does not have the used fonts installed you can `nano` or `vim` the .xcf file and it will show you which font is used for which spans of text; ex: `<span font=\"Font Name\"</span>`

Answer (score 17):

Apart from opening the file in a text editor, I found another way to do so from within GIMP, [mentioned in a German GIMP forum](http://www.gimpforum.de/showthread.php?p=126181).

This is a Python script that can be executed from the GIMP's built-in Python console:

```
for image in gimp.image_list():
  for layer in image.layers:
    try:
      layer.parasite_find('gimp-text-layer').data
    except AttributeError:
      pass
```

It runs across all images loaded, across all layers, and dumps the data of all text layers, including font names.

Comment: I'd never used the gimp python console (or much python at all) before so I had to figure this out...I had to indent by four spaces per indentation stop or I got a syntax error.

Comment: Same. I copypasta'd into text editor, removed dots (`...`) from each line, copypasta'd into `GIMP > Filters > Python-Fu -> Console` then hit `enter` two or three times to make it work. Success!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me on Mac, so here's a solution that works with macOS grep:

```
grep -a 'font \"' file.xcf | sort | uniq -c
```

Tested with Grep version "grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD". Sample output:

```
$ grep -a 'font \"' file.xcf | sort | uniq -c
   1 (font "Alison Ultra-Light")
  11 (font "Ambient")
```